# rearranging equation to create new form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation:

$$h=\alpha_2+\beta_2\left[\left(\frac{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}{\beta_1-\beta_2}\right)-\left(\frac{\gamma_1}{\beta_1-\beta_2}\right)k\right]$$

with which I need to obtain an equation for 'h' in terms of 'k' of the form:

$$h=\pi_3+\pi_4k$$

I am truly horrible at rearranging these kinds of equations so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking why $A+B(C-D \cdot k) = (A+B C) + (- B D) \cdot k\,$?

Comment: but so as your equation is given has it the form $$h=A+B(C-Dk)$$

Comment: essentially I'm running a regression and need to express the structural form equations in terms of their reduced-form equations. 

what you've just written may be the answer (I may be over complicating things in my head!) in that;

$$\pi_3=\alpha_2+\beta_2\left(\frac{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}{\beta_1-\beta_2}\right)$$

and 

$$\pi_4=-\beta_2\left(\frac{\gamma_1}{\beta_1-\beta_2}\right)$$

Comment: @j.sch That's right.